# Does swagger depend on jax-rs or spring mvc?

Tags: java, rest, maven, swagger

I want to create a swagger json file from class with swagger annotations. It is so happened that I don't use spring mvc or jax-rs. Can swagger file be generated just having swagger maven plugin and swagger-annotations dependency?

I created a class with swagger annotations. Tried to generate a swagger json file, all I saw was - the info about the api, which I mentioned in the swagger-maven-plugin.

Once I added `@Path` of jax-rs to my api class - everything generated successfully, all methods, all responses

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is if you using [swagger-maven-plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin).

> Supports SpringMvc & JAX-RS